# how to add a navigation drawer in an existing layout

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a layout with a listview.xml as shown below

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main">
  <ListView
     android:id="@+id/Planets"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:divider="#b5b5b5"
     android:dividerHeight="2dp"
     android:background="#fff"/>

 <ListView
     android:id="@+id/stars"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:divider="#b5b5b5"
     android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
 </ListView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I want to add a navigation drawer in this layout. For this purpose I have this layout.

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I don't know how to integrate the drawer in my listview.xml, I've done something like this but not working for me.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 

<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>                     

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/planets"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:background="#fff"/>
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/stars"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and I don't know what is the correct way of doing this. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean how to integrate the drawer in my listview.xml? Your second layout appears to be correct.

Comment: yes I have to integrate in my list.xml. I want to merge them in single layout.

Comment: your listview.xml is the layout for your Fragment, right?

Comment: no it is for an activity.

Comment: For your approach, you should have your listview.xml layout set for a Fragment (for example, ListViewFragment) and add it to the FrameLayout that is part of your Activity layout, inside onCreate() method.

Comment: you mean to say that I should change my Activity class to a Fragment?

Comment: No, you should create a Fragment and put it inside your Activity layout, on FrameLayout. See my answer and the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a Fragment to hold your two `ListViews` layout (`listview.xml`). That fragment will populate your `FrameLayout` (that is part of your `Activity` layout) component at runtime.

Your Activity will then have a `DrawerLayout` with a `FrameLayout` inside it (which contains whatever Fragment layout you define inside it) and a `ListView`, which contains your drawer menu items.

For more information, check [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) to implement the correct approach on having a DrawerLayout.

Answer (score 0):

DrawerLayout should be the root element of layout file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/main">



<!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>


 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/planets"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:background="#fff"/>
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/stars"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp" >
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
  </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```